# How do I Change div background color when link inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I Change background color to green when link is clicked  and keep the color green until I click the link again then the color must be white

I have this code so far:

```
    <% foreach (var group in Model.Results)
       { %>       

         <div id="group-select<%: group.GroupId %>" style="width:95%; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px;" >
            <h3><a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: group.GroupId %>)" id="changer<%: group.GroupId %>"  ><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
         </div>

    <% } %>
```

and the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function OnGroupClicked(groupId) {
  $("#changer" + groupId).on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = $('#group-select' + groupId),
        green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
        white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

    if (body.css("backgroundColor") !== green) {
      body.css("backgroundColor", green);
    } else {
      body.css("backgroundColor", white);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

can some one help me please?
the color green wil show that a specific group is selected and when it is white it is NOT selected. So when the page first loads up it will be white. I click on it and it is green and stays green until I click it again.

thanks

Comment: Can't you play with `a:visited` CSS style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

http://jsbin.com/evupih/1/edit

The problem with your code is, you check for the hex value. But if you read the backgroundColor, you will get the rgb value ;-)

Comment: i need to have my link as an actionlink, can i give it an id ie give the link an id?

Comment: I don't know what this is: HTML.ActionLink, but it wouldn't make sense if you couln't set an id..

Comment: it is asp.net mvc 3 with html5, the code in that link works but ic makes my whole body green i only need the div green and in html5 you cannot have body tag in a div tag, therfore i am not sure i can use that code?

Comment: i got it to work but only trouble now is I must click twice before the div turns green? please see OP i edited it with the new code, thanks

Comment: I have updated the example above, it should fit your needs now. See here:
http://jsbin.com/evupih/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

Why did you don't create a css class called "clicked" like:

```
.clicked{background-color:#00CC00}
```

Then do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnGroupClicked(groupId)
{
  if ($("#ColorHidden" + groupId).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $("#ColorHidden" + groupId).removeClass("clicked")
  } else {
    $("#ColorHidden" + groupId).addClass("clicked")
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can make it work with the code I have currently please? with your code when i clickon the link the div stays white

Comment: I guess you should use:
target.css("background-color", green);
instead of:
target.css("backgroundColor", green);

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find the div enclosing each link:

```
$(function(){
  $("#changer").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).parent(),
        green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
        white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

    if(target.css("backgroundColor") !== green){
      target.css("backgroundColor", green);
    }else{
      target.css("backgroundColor", white);
    }

  });
});
```

Once this is working, you could refine it by using classes and hasClass/addClass/removeClass as suggested by @jimmy - it's more flexible that way if you wanted to go, say, from pink to black.

This assumes the parent element is the group-select div. If you change the layout around the links, this may break and you will need to specifically target the divs using the id - I haven't taken that approach here for speed.